# Google Syntax Highligher PHP Preg_replace

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, syntax-highlighting, preg-replace

Im using Wordpress Google Syntax Highligther plugin and I've came across a problem using the PHP class.

Basically its adding !-- and -- to the  for some reason.

If theres anyone who knows how to do preg_replace I would be very greatful if someone could help me out.

http://thefinishedbox.com/tutorials/wordpress/adding-wordpress-3-0-post-thumbnail-using-a-custom-field/

Theres a link to it, you can see what i mean.

I basically have this HTML:

```
<pre name="code" class="php">
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</pre>
```

and it generates this:

```
<!--?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?-->
<!--?php endwhile; ?-->
```

I need to somehow get rid of the !-- and -- if thats possible?

Regards.

Comment: `<!-- -->` is an html comment.  Seems like it doesn't like your php tags.  Maybe Wordpress is escaping `<? ?>` into something the syntax highlighter doesn't like?

Comment: @banzaimonkey Its running on the PHP version of the highlighter but I still have no idea why its generating them... If i put it into the html version it will comment it all out.

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding the inner HTML before passing it to the parser, otherwise what's generated is invalid HTML (considering `<?` is an XML processessing instruction, and not a valid HTML statement, so it might comment it out so that it always produces clean HTML). :

```
$html = htmlspecialchars($html);
$code = '<pre name="code" class="php">'.$html.'</pre>';
```

Comment: Where would I put this? Thanks for the answer much appreciated.

Comment: Where do you have the syntax highlighting?  Is it in an article?  If so, your editor should do it for you.  You could also try removing the `<?php` and `?>` tags from the post (since you're telling the highlighter it's PHP already)...

Comment: I'm not really following lol, Google Syntax Highligher is a plugin for wordpress, you use html attributes i.e name="code" to run the plugin and class="php" to define which js file to use.

Comment: Well, then try removing the `<?php` and `?>` from the post and see if that does anything...

Comment: Thats not something I'd be willing to do as I'll be using it as markup for tutorials. :/